# validate numeric fields with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regExp to validate an input.

The input should have a numeric field, with not more than 3 digits before the comma and not more than 2 digits after the comma.

I tried this regexp : [0-9]{1,3}([.|,][0-9]{1,2})?

But it does not work. The value 1234.567 is validated as ok although it should not.

Here the code i used to try this :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="regExp1" type="text" value = "[0-9]{1,3}([\.|,][0-9]{1,2})?" />
<input type="button" value="->" onclick="applyRegExp(regExp1,test1)"> 
<input id="test1" type="text" />
<input type="button" onclick="TestRegExp(test1,test1Result)" value="test"> 
<div id="test1Result" ></div>

</body>
</html>

///.. test.js :
function applyRegExp(input1,input2){

    input2.pattern = input1.value;
}



    function TestRegExp( inputField,resultField){

        var regexp = new RegExp(inputField.pattern);
        var value = inputField.value;

        if (regexp.test(value)){
            resultField.innerHTML = inputField.name + " ok";
        }else
        {
            resultField.innerHTML = inputField.name + " not ok";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want

```
^\d{1,3}([.|,]\d{1,2})?$
```

**UPDATE:** We just check for the string to match **from the beginning to the end (with `^` and `$`)**

. What is going on is just we allow 3 digits in a row (any), accept a dot or a comma but excpect with it at least 1 digit and at most 2.

Comment: A little explanation would help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
^\d{1,3}([.|,]\d{1,2})?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: This expects a float **only**

Comment: @aduch, Didnt notice the quantifier in quesn , Thanks :)