# Is there a library to parse numbers in R?

Tags: r

I consistently run across the need to parse numbers from text.  When I search on the web, I find suggestions that usually use gsub or grep.  It seems like there should be something more standard.  A library to parse numbers from text.  Is there one that I have missed?

Two examples:

```
#parse percentiles: 80%
as.numeric(gsub("\\%", "", values))
```

and

```
#parse comma delimited numbers: 12,500
as.numeric(gsub(",","", values))
```

Is there a better way to do this than to hand-craft a parser each time?

Comment: Hi Steve, recommendation questions are off topic on SO, maybe you can rephrase your question, to avoid to get it closed?

Comment: in particular, what scope do you have in mind?  Consider the  `?prettyNum` function and all the ways it can encode numbers (scientific notation, `big.mark`, `small.mark`, leading percentages, dollar signs, ...).  You might be better off looking on SO for a pretty-good [regexp answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574170/validate-numeric-fields-with-regexp) to this general question ...

Comment: This isn't a recommendation question.  This is asking if there is a way to do this that isn't hand-crafting a parser every time.  There should be a specific answer.  Yes, there is a library and it is called X or no, there isn't a library.

Comment: Interesting point. [I just asked for clarification about this on meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257649/are-is-there-a-package-rather-than-whats-the-best-package-questions-ok)

Answer (score 4):

Its not clear what the scope of this is but the following parses either of the inputs shown by first removing all non-numerics:

```
d <- c("80%", "12,500")
as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", d))
## [1] 80 12500
```

Comment: I think the bigger-picture point is that it's easier to just nuke the non-numeric information (*unless* you need to deal with data that have decimal separators) than to parse all possible numeric formats (monetary values, percentages, comma-separated, ...) something analogous to the `lubridate::ymd()` function, which tries to guess information about formats, might be useful, but I don't think it exists.

Comment: Yes.  I am looking for something like lubridate for numbers.

Comment: It is better use gsub('[^\\.0-9]','',d) in case of d containing decimal point, such as d <- c("80.32%", "12,500.33")

Comment: @ShenglinChen: what if the decimal separator is a comma instead (and the dot is a big-mark separator, i.e. "80.465,01" as in some European locales)?